# How to use angular1.x link function

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

hello everyone I have some question of ng1 , this link function can't capture the `li`,

```
var a=document.querySelectorAll(".carousel ul");
console.log(a);
```

was output the `"[ul]"` but

```
var b=document.querySelectorAll(".carousel ul li");
console.log(b)
```

was output `“[]”` why link can't capture the `.carousel ul li`?.

```
 <html lang="en" ng-app="myApp">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
    <script src="../js/angular.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="myController">
<carousel my-image="image"></carousel>
</body>
<style>
    .carousel{
        width:300px;
        height:200px;
        display:block;
        overflow:hidden;;
    }
    .carousel ul{
        position:relative;
        left:0;
        list-style:none;
        padding:0;
        margin:0;
        width:900px;
        height:100%;
    }
    .carousel ul li {
        float:left;
        width:300px;
        height:200px;

    }
</style>
<script>
    angular.module("myApp",[])
            .controller("myController",function($scope){
                $scope.image=[
                    {'title':"1",'img':"../image/a.jpg"},
                    {'title':"2",'img':"../image/g.jpg"},
                    {'title':"3",'img':"../image/z.jpg"}
                ];
            })
            .directive("carousel",function(){
                return {
                    replace: true,
                    restrict: "EA",
                    scope: {
                        img: "=myImage"
                    },
                    transclude: true,
                    template: '<div class="carousel"> <ul> <li ng-repeat="i in img"> <img width="100%" height="100%" src="{{i.img}}"  alt=""/> </li> </ul> </div>',
                    link: function (scope, elem, attr) {
                        var a=document.querySelectorAll(".carousel ul");
                        console.log(a);
                        var b=document.querySelectorAll(".carousel ul li");
                        console.log(b);
                    }
                }
            });
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: Remove `replace: true` and try using `elem` to find the child elements

Comment: var i=elem.find("ul li");  console.log(i); li was [] !

Answer (score 1):

You cannot capture the `li` element since by the time your link function is called, angular haven't finished the DOM's manipulation yet. Content in 'ng-repeat' has not be properly manipulated.

Try put it in `scope.$evalAsync`

```
link: function (scope, elem, attr) {
                        //...
                        scope.$evalAsync(function(){
                           var b=document.querySelectorAll(".carousel ul li");
                           console.log(b);
                        })

                }
```

UPDATE:

Sorry $evalAsync don't work in this case. Should use $timeout instead.

```
.directive("carousel",function($timeout){
                return {
                    replace: true,
                    restrict: "EA",
                    scope: {
                        img: "=myImage"
                    },
                    transclude: true,
                    template: '<div class="carousel"> <ul> <li ng-repeat="i in img"> <img width="100%" height="100%" src="{{i.img}}"  alt=""/> </li> </ul> </div>',
                    link: function (scope, elem, attr) {
                        var a=document.querySelectorAll(".carousel ul");
                        console.log(a);
                        $timeout(function(){
                          var b=document.querySelectorAll(".carousel ul li");
                          console.log(b);
                        },0)

                    }
                }
            });
```